# ionic2 crash on navigation [navPush]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I started building with ionic 2 today, and was making great progress.  I had 3-4 pages with navigation working, and then something broke that I can't figure out.

Now whenever I execute a simple navigation to any other page I get the error below.  I started uncommenting all my code, then created a brand new blank project (twice), with as little code as possible.  It's still happening and I don't know why.  Any help?

Steps:
1) Create new project

```
ionic start IonicLogin blank --v2
```

2) Add a new page:

```
ionic g page landing
```

3) Update home.html and home.ts to navigate to landing page (html below)

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="signupPage">
```

4) Update app.module.ts to include the new landing page (import & entryComponents)

5) Run

```
ionic serve -c
```

Everything builds, the app loads, but clicking on the button I get this:

```
4     183512   error    invalid page component: undefined
5     183527   error    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false
7     183527   error    Error: Uncaught (in promise): false
    at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8546)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8296
    at Object.ti.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:46775:23)
    at NavControllerBase._queueTrns (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:46781:20)
    at NavControllerBase.push (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:46662:21)
    at NavPush.onClick (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55680:23)
    at _View_HomePage0._handle_click_17_0 (HomePage.ngfactory.js:288:34)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:10947:24
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:34565:36
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:34685:111
6     183527   error    ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
```

Comment: Can you please include the code of the `home.ts` file?

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras!  Can you tell me if the solution below is the best way to expose a page type to a template for use in navigation?  The pattern works, but it doesn't strike me as intuitive.  Is there a better way to fix?

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue :) And yes, the way you did it seems to be the way Ionic team does it in the docs, so I guess that's the best way to do it. That being said, I do prefer to use a `click` event to push a new page (instead of the attribute `[navPush]`), but the end result is exactly the same.

Comment: Awesome - thanks again!  I wish the error that happened in this scenario pointed me at home.ts.  At least this is now on SO if anyone stumbles into the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @sebaferreras! Due to the comment asking for my home.ts file, I looked a bit closer there.  That's where the problem was.  I had **landingPage** as an instance of type LandingPage.  Swapping it to below got things working again.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {LandingPage} from '../landing/landing';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

      landingPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.landingPage = LandingPage;
  }  
}
```